# Changing PhD, who and how to tell first?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, cv, interview, quitting

I want to leave and change my current PhD after 3 months in this new city (France). I still haven't told my current supervisors because, for economic reasons, I do not want to get fired while looking for new places. I don't want to try to talk to them to make small changes in the PhD because there's nothing that can be changed: I dislike the topic, the city is unsafe, I have a bad work environment and group, and I experience a lot of isolation...

I do not know how to put my current situation in the CV, nor how to tell potential new supervisors. If I include that I'm doing a PhD in the CV, they may be surprised, search for my lab and contact the people there, spreading the word that I could be leaving. But if I don't put it there and they find out that I'm doing a PhD (by Googling my name, maybe), they may think of me as a not honest person or liar.

I could easily tell them I'm in the trial period of the PhD, which is 2 months, to justify that the topic is something that doesn't suit me (even though I'm 2 weeks over it, but it's no worries because I can still leave the PhD, I just need to get a signature from the supervisor, which I think she can understand). I think the less-worse idea is to include it in the CV, but not mention it in my motivation letter, as my current project doesn't motivate me, but my master and master thesis does.

Any suggestions / similar experiences? I'm having a lot of stress due to this. I have to work while I look for new places and I'm not clear how to present myself.

Comment: Where are you in the world? There is typically a process and procedure for firing someone, and I really doubt you'd be dismissed summarily from a PhD program as long as you're doing any responsibilities attached to your assistantship.

Comment: Anyways, it seems like a lot of this falls into your own responsibility and due diligence. I doubt the safety of your city has changed in a year. Bad work environment can surprise, but what has come up in 3 months that is so serious that it can't be fixed? Why did you join this group in the first place? Has any misconduct occurred that you could report? Isolation is... probably mostly your responsibility and going somewhere else might luck you into better connections, but it's just as likely you'll be in the same boat. You have to meet your own friends, they aren't provided by a grad program.

Comment: I am in France and I come from Spain. I just don't like the culture, introversion and sarcasm/second meanings here. And the group feeling is just very bad luck. Everyone that I talk with that is doing a PhD tell me they have a good environment and they don't feel rejected.

Comment: Isolation isn't my responsability, it's everyone's responsability. It is human to try to make someone new feel welcome, talk to them, etc

Comment: Unfortunately I think that expectation is likely to mean that isolation will follow you wherever you go. Most people do PhDs in places that are new to them and it's not the same environment for making friends that university is for many undergraduates (this is not necessarily unique to a PhD; people taking their first jobs of any type in a new place encounter this). Work colleagues may become friends, but they aren't required to be. They should not be outright hostile, of course.

Comment: So i should expect for people to not be human and not care about me, wherever i go? That standard is very low. I do not accept it, and it is not the norm. That's why i wanna leave. I get that the first days of a new place may be weird and lonely. But 3 months is enough time for me to realise that they just don't care about me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151504/discussion-between-nico-and-bryan-krause).

Comment: Please consider getting counseling, asap.

Comment: When I was doing my PhD, my name was not on my university's website. Are you sure your name is on your university's website? If your name is not on your university's website, how can anyone find out that you're doing your PhD?

Comment: well, if you search my full name on google, you can see my thesis name and my name on  like the 6th result

Comment: By "thesis name" are you referring to the name of your of PhD thesis which you will write in a few years from now? Does Google search reveal that you're a PhD student?